# C Overwrite data strftime macro

Tags: c, strftime

I am trying to write a small log system.

```
void write_log_msg(char * type, char * file_name, int line_number, char * fmt, ...);
```

To call this function in a nice way, I used macro

```
#define log_msg(fmt, ...) (write_log_msg(LOG, __FILE__, __LINE__, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__))
```

I want to format the date of now and I use the function `strftime` to do that. But when I do, it seems it overwrites the data stored in `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` and I can't tell why.

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
char date_str[DATE_SIZE];
char time_str[TIME_SIZE];
struct tm * local_now = localtime(&now);
printf("file %s\n", file_name);
printf("line %d\n", line_number);
status = strftime(date_str, DATE_SIZE, "%b %d %Y", local_now);
if(status == 0){
    printf("Error 1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
status = strftime(time_str, TIME_SIZE, "%X", local_now);
if(status == 0){
    printf("Error 2");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

When I check for the content of the value of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` before `strftime`, it works just fine then the `__FILE__` takes the value of `date_str` and `line_str` I can't even tell. Any idea why it would do that ? Thanks !
Any idea why it would do that ?

Comment: What is the value of DATE_SIZE and TIME_SIZE? It looks like you might be overwriting data on the stack.

Comment: It is 15 for date and 10 time. How can that be? Genuine question

Comment: I really do not know. Can you come up with a small program containing the function and its call, and demonstrating the bug? Maybe running it under valgrind or such might give some hint.

Comment: Good idea, I'll do that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Apart from the obvious mistypes (`file_name` and `fmt` , and arguably `type`, though its usage is unclear) should be `const char *`, not `char*`,  I do not see a problem here. Your code shows no evidence of inspecting `file_name` after the `strftime` calls to substantiate your claim, nor is any output shown at all for that matter, so more details are needed (such as a proper [mcve]).